# Looping through an array and executing statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp

Is it possible to loop through this array in mysql and execute a delete statement where the category_id column is equal to the current value been looped in that array below.

```
      $row =   [
            'type' => '3',
            'name'  => 'Warez',
            'category_id' => 'IAB26-2',
            'parent_category_id' => 'IAB26'
        ],
        [
            'type' => '3',
            'name'  => 'Spyware/Malware',
            'category_id' => 'IAB26-3',
            'parent_category_id' => 'IAB26'
        ],
        [
            'type' => '3',
            'name'  => 'Copyright Infringement',
            'category_id' => 'IAB26-4',
            'parent_category_id' => 'IAB26'
        ],
        [
            'type' => '3',
            'name'  => 'Uncategorized',
            'category_id' => 'IAB24'
        ]
```

I have tried this

```
 foreach($row as $value) {
       $this->execute('DELETE from categories WHERE category_id = '.$value['category_id'].'');
    }
```

doesn't seem to work as it should. Is there is better Sql command for this kind of operation?

Comment: You could always turn that array into an XML document and pass it to sql for deletions.

Comment: You can do something with `DELETE ..... WHERE category_id IN (.....)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is insecure because it's possible to inject SQL. So an attacker might execute whatever he wants in your SQL query.

**If** this is really CakePHP code, why aren't you using the ORM? You cleary should read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html the Table Objects and Deleting Data section. If not don't use wrong tags.

**Assuming** this is done in a table object, the most simple way to do this is:

```
$ids = Hash::extract($data, '{n}.category_id');
if (!empty($ids)) {
    $this->deleteAll([
        'category_id IN' => $ids
    ]);
}
```

Comment: do Hash work in migration, i'm working on a migration file @burzum

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to wrap the value you concatenate with quotes (because it's not numeric).

Something like this:

```
$this->execute('DELETE from categories WHERE category_id = "'.$value['category_id'].'"');
```

However, doing `DELETE ... WHERE` as suggested in one of the comments would yield better performance.

Also, note that if the data comes from the user then it may be susceptible to SQL injection, so you should read about and use parameterized queries rather than concatenation.

Comment: Please do not insert dynamic data into queries directly, even if you think the data is safe!!! Whenever possible, use bindings! It's {the_current_year}, SQL injections shouldn't be a thing anymore :(

Comment: @ndm yes, I mentioned that. Maybe try to read to the end before you downvote. This is a fix to the bug in his code, and understanding what he did wrong can be valuable for him in other places, and not only in queries.

Comment: I didn't downvoted it, and yes, you mentioned SQL injections, I read that, but you showed the wrong usage anyways, hence my comment. You know that people are lazy, and that those who really need to learn this lesson, won't do the reading, they will just copy the stuff and go on with their day. I also wanted to highlight that it's not just "user" data that is dangerous, but even data from which you think it might be safe, even embedded data might turn into something dangerous when changed incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

Using an IN clause

```
$list = array(); foreach ($row as $item) {
    $list[] = "'{$item['category_id']}'";
}
$sql = 'DELETE from categories WHERE category_id IN ('.implode(',',$list).')';
$this->execute( $sql );
```

Comment: Same thing, [**please use bindings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308551/looping-through-an-array-and-executing-statement-in-mysql#comment85638889_49308731)! Never rely on incoming data to be safe!